# Randomizing a count up timer to finish within a specific period of time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a simple count up timer that will count up to a specified number and finish after a period of time (65 secs).  I'm wondering how I could randomize the count up a little bit so that it counts faster at some points and slower at others but still have it finish at the specified end time.  This is the function I'm using to count up.  maxCount is dynamic but I just set it to 101 for this example.

I setup a jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/bz2Hz/

```
function fillCounter() {
var maxCount = 101;
var interval = 65000/maxCount;
var val = 0;
count();
function count(){
    if ( val <= maxCount ){
        val++;
        $('.results-number').html(val);
        setTimeout(count,interval);
    }
}
}
```

Any tips would be appreciated.  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the interval also as random

<kbd>[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chauhangs/bz2Hz/2/)</kbd>

```
function fillCounter() {
var maxCount = 101;
var interval = 65000/maxCount;
var val = 0;
count();
function count(){
    if ( val <= maxCount ){
        val++;
        $('.results-number').html(val);

        setTimeout(count,interval);

        var plusOrMinus = Math.random() < 0.5 ? -100 :100;
        console.log(plusOrMinus);
        interval =  (interval + Math.floor((Math.random())+plusOrMinus));

        console.log(interval);
    }
  }
}
fillCounter();
```

EDIT :

You can try like this <kbd>[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chauhangs/bz2Hz/5/)</kbd>

1. Set up a timer

   ```
   var count = 65;
   var counter = setInterval(timer, 1000); 
   function timer() {
   counting();
   count = count - 1;
      if (count <= 0) {
       clearInterval(counter);
       return;
    }

    }
   ```

Then print your values by setting a random interval

```
  var val = 0;

  function printer() {
    val++;
     $('.results-number').html(val);
  }

 function counting() {
   var multi = Math.random() < 0.5 ? 1 : 10000;

   interval = Math.floor((Math.random() * multi));

    console.log(interval);
    setTimeout(printer, interval);
 }
```

Comment: Thanks NullPointerException, the only problem is that it doesn't take into account the 65 seconds.  That's the part I'm struggling with, how to randomize the count up but still have it finish in 65 seconds.

Comment: Updated the answer with another fiddle

Comment: Ah, yes.  This will work.  I had to make some adjustments because the number I'm counting up to doesn't necessarily equal the length of time it has to count for but I can add that.  Thank you.

Comment: Yes that for sure because this one is only counting till 65